# When I use base64_decode why it return at the end characters like ÃÜ or 7? they are wrong

Tags: php, base64, decode

When I am encrypting in base64 the encripted value is right and I can see normal values of the results i want, The problems appears when I use the function to decode base64 (base64_decode).

In the results appears , at the end, the characters like ÃÜ or 7. I set  two cases and all code I am using

Could you help me please? I send you all the code implied in the pages...

==================================================================================

### CASE 1:

#### String:

```
CIF_NIF::multiline++++1--2++aaaa--bbbbbb
```

#### base64_encoded:

```
Q0lGX05JRjo6bXVsdGlsaW5lKysrKzEtLTIrK2FhYWEtLWJiYmJiYg==
```

#### base64_decoded:

```
CIF_NIF::multiline++++1--2++aaaa--bbbbbb ÃÜ
```

==================================================================================

### CASE 2:

#### String:

```
VALOR::varchar++bool
```

#### base64_encoded:

```
VkFMT1I6OnZhcmNoYXIrK2Jvb2w=
```

#### base64_decoded:

```
VALOR::varchar++bool7
```

==================================================================================

### AJAX CALL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _ajax_url,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    data: {
        info: data
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    //dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {....
    }
});
```

==================================================================================

### PHP CODE:

#### encoding function ...

```
return base64_encode($res);
```

when I echo de return in the explorer the results are the values I set before.

#### dencoding function ...

```
return base64_encode($res);
```

when I echo de return in the explorer the results are the values I set before.

#### $string_b64 is thje coded in base64 value, you can se the real values before...

```
$string =  base64_decode($string_b64);
```

==================================================================================
I add you the headers of my php page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

## I don't know if it can implies a rare behavior in base64_de code.

the function code are:

```
public static function encrypting($array) {
    $res = "";
    $delimiter = array("||", "::", "++", "--");

    if (is_array($array)) {

        $gen = "";
        //echo implode(">", $array[0]);
        //echo count($array);
        foreach($array as $clave = > $valor) {
            $aux = [];
            if ($gen != "") $gen. = $delimiter[0];

            foreach($valor as $v) {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    array_push($aux, implode($delimiter[3], $v));
                } else {
                    array_push($aux, $v);
                }
            }

            $gen = "$clave$delimiter[1]".implode($delimiter[2], $aux);

        }

        $res = $gen;
    } else $res = $array;

    return base64_encode($res);
    //return $res;
}


public static function decrypting($string_b64) {
    $res = [];

    $string = imap_base64($string_b64);

    echo $string;

    $delimiter = array("||", "::", "++", "--");

    $pas1 = explode($delimiter[0], $string);

    foreach($pas1 as $valor1) {
        $i = 0;

        $pas2 = explode($delimiter[1], $valor1);

        $aux = [];

        $pas3 = explode($delimiter[2], $pas2[1]);

        foreach($pas3 as $valor2) {

            if (strpos($valor2, $delimiter[3]) > 0) $aux[] = explode($delimiter[3], $valor2);
            else $aux[] = trim($valor2);

        }

        $res[$pas2[0]] = $aux;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

==================================================================================
EXAMPLE OF USE:

```
$personalitzats1 = array("CIF_NIF" => array(false, "", "Aquest Camp es personalitzat...."));

$value = encrypting($personalitzats1)

decrypting($value);
```

The problem is in decrypting I echo the value after base64_decode and it is when the characters appear.

I have saved the page as **ISO**: **cp1252** codification (the standard) I don't think so iti s the problem.

If I use an external web page like http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ and I set in the textarea the value Q0lGX05JRjo6bXVsdGlsaW5lKysrKzEtLTIrK2FhYWEtLWJiYmJiYg== the result is the correct.

Comment: In case #1 if you take the encoded string decode it on http://www.base64decode.org/ it does not show the (ÃÜ) same with case #2

Comment: can be maybe the iso is cp1252? or the version of php? I am using PHP Version 5.4.16